# SDI loop through with LTC embedder

Tags: video, sync, timecode

I was wondering if there’s a converter out there that would take a HD-SDI in, as well as a LTC in, and an SDI out.

We currently have video feeds with no timecode embedded and was trying to loop through a feed of timecode which we can feed from a BNC.

I’m also seeing if it’s possible to make too! I know it is a thing that can happen considering Atomos Shoguns can feed in and LTC. I just need that without the screen.

If i fed to BNCs (a T Bar) into one out would that work? Is video and timecode able to be merged or would it be read as two feed signals?

Comment: You definitely can't use a BNC T do combine the signals like that, even worse, the input video wouldn't work at all. You can make it but not just by soldering a few components together; it will take some form of processing. Just to confirm, you have an analog LTC input that you want embedded into the HANC (RP188/ST12-2) on the HD-SDI, right?

Comment: ATOMOS has a LTC converter that inserts if into an SDI signal for around $90 from B&H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to make, but think FPGA with 3 Gig SERDES (so probably a modest Kintex 7 or something similar) with a couple of SDI line IO parts (TI) and maybe a PLL from SI Labs, add some power conversion and a mess of VHDL, job done.

Maybe a few months work.

Obviously if you have LTC you can stripe that onto an audio track just using any old audio embedder, but I am guessing that does not really do it for you?

I would be a little surprised if YellowBrix or maybe Decimator Designs do not have a box that does this.

Regards, Dan.